# Transform nested array into normal array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have following array, that I need to transform before inserting into database. Right now my data are looking like this:

[image]

And I would like to save the data in this format:

[image]

So far I have tried this code, but with no luck:

```
const buildTvTimeline = (r: Data) =>
{
   const meta = get(r, ["meta", "tv"], []);

   return Object.keys(meta).map((index: any) =>
   {
      const game = meta[index].game;
      const tile = meta[index].tile;
      const dates = meta[index].dates;

      const data = dates.map((r: any) => ({ ...r, tile: tile, game: game }));

           return data;
       });
 }
 const timeline = buildTvTimeline(r);
        
 const data = Object.keys(timeline).map((index) => 
 {
      return timeline[index];
 });

 set(r, ["timeline", "tv"], data);
```

Any ideas what can I do to transform the format of the first array into the format of the second array?

Thank you in advance

Comment: [`array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) is what you are looking for.

Comment: @theblackgigant gonna accept your answer as soon as I can. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Merge/flatten an array of arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10865025/merge-flatten-an-array-of-arrays)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array.flat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) to turn a multidimensional into a flat array.

Since i can't use your data i created my own.

```js
const tv = [
  [
    {
      a: "a"
    },
    {
      b: "b"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      c: "c"
    },
    {
      d: "d"
    }
  ]
];

const tvFlat = tv.flat();

console.log(tvFlat);
```

Comment: That fixes the issue for me. Thank you.